# Why is `GIT_EDITOR` set to `:` (colon) within my `commit-msg` hook?

Tags: git, environment-variables, githooks

I have a `commit-msg` hook that attempts to read the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable.

In my shell `$GIT_EDITOR` is not set.

```
$ echo $GIT_EDITOR

$ test -z "$GIT_EDITOR" && echo "GIT_EDITOR empty"
GIT_EDITOR empty
```

However within the `commit-msg` hook it appears to be set to `:`. Why is this? Is there away to prevent it from happening?

I've tested this on multiple machines and I'm seeing the same behaviour everywhere.

Reduced test case:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/git-hook-editor-test && cd /tmp/git-hook-editor-test/
$ git init
$ echo 'echo "GIT_EDITOR =" $GIT_EDITOR && exit 1' > .git/hooks/commit-msg
$ touch foo.txt
$ git add foo.txt
$ git commit -m 'foo' foo.txt
GIT_EDITOR = :
```

Comment: Setting the `GIT_EDITOR` to a value e.g. `nano` in the outer shell doesn't help either. The value is still `:` within the `commit-msg` hook.

Comment: Fascinating.  Hard to believe that this is intended behavior.  :D

Comment: Can you show your `commit-msg` file?

Comment: Hi @JakeHenningsgaard. I can but I'm still seeing the same issue with the reduced test case in the question: `echo "GIT_EDITOR =" $GIT_EDITOR && exit 1`, so I don't believe anything else in the hook should be relevant. The original hook is: https://github.com/tommarshall/git-good-commit/blob/v0.6.0/hook.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) (near the bottom of the description for "pre-commit"):

> All the `git commit` hooks are invoked with the environment variable `GIT_EDITOR=:` if the command will not bring up an editor to modify the commit message.

If you leave off the `-m`, you should see it change to something more meaningful.

Comment: As a further note, [with `-e` or `--edit`, "The message taken from file with `-F`, command line with `-m`, and from commit object with `-C` are usually used as the commit log message unmodified. This option lets you further edit the message taken from these sources."](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit--e)